# Firestore/Zapier Structured Query - Basics

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, zapier

I'm trying to set up a very simple Zapier connection to Firestore; the results of the following test are "We couldn't find a record". What am I missing? I've tried different variations of path and field strings.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Within the Query you are using `list` for `fieldPath`. This is the reason you are getting `we could not find a record`. Instead it should be `name`, which is a field in the Firestore collection. So please change the value for `fieldPath` to `name` and it should work. After changing the Query should be the following -

```
"orderBy" : [{
"field":{
  "fieldPath": "name"
  },
  "direction" : "DESCENDING"
  }]
```

Comment: Does this resolve the issue?